# Slow down rate of C++ commands

Tags: performance, visual-c++

I have a linear actuator that I am sending commands to via Visual C++. I want to do cycle testing with it (ie, extend, retract, extend, retract...). However, I want to slow down the rate at which Visual C++ sends the LA commands. The reason is that the commands are being sent too fast for the LA to respond.

Is it possible to "slow down" a C++ program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at this answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/902271/557748

Comment: ok. trying the `Sleep(2);` function and its not working. the program builds but doesn't wait 2 seconds when encounter the function.

Comment: Is this being run on a PC or is this being compiled for a micro controller?

Comment: On a PC. does Sleep(2) cause the program to 'sleep' for 2 seconds or 2 milliseconds? If it is milliseconds, then I need to try Sleep(2000) and see if that works. I'll update you on whether or not that fixes the problem.