# Write a C++ program to print a number from 1 to a user entered number. Only accept numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: c++

I'm currently in a C++ class and I'm not sure what to do in this particular assignment. The book isn't very helpful and I feel like I need assistance. 
Here is the assignment:

Write a C++ program to print a number from 1 to a user entered number.  Only accept numbers from 1 to 100;
Example:
Enter the number:  15
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15.

At first, I thought, maybe it was a guessing game, but it asks to PRINT all the numbers from 1-100. I know I need to use a for loop. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
{

 int num = 15; 
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)

}
system ("Pause")
```

Comment: You should read about `cin`

Comment: NEVER use `system` unless you really know what you're doing, or your teacher is forcing you to use it for some dumb reason.

Comment: Unfortunately, budding C++ developers are sometimes forced to use technically-inferior operating systems where nonsense like `system("pause");` is required just to be able to read your program's output, otherwise it goes to that great bit bucket in the sky.

Comment: I know about cin, eavidan for reminding me! For most of our coding, if we don't use the system 'pause' the screen won't stay up long enough to send in a SS for the assignments

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: You're _never_ forced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you need to print numbers from the 1 to the user-inputed number (but only accept numbers from 1 to 100). Then the following should work:

```
// This will import the libraries we need for input and output
#include <iostream>                                                             

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {                           

    // This will get the number from the user          
    int num;                                                                    
    std::cin >> num;                         

    // We check if it's in the right range; if so, print the numbers we want                                   
    if(0 < num && num <= 100) {                                                 
        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++) {                                         
            std::cout << i << std::endl;                                        
        }                                                                       
    }                                                                           
    return 0;                                                                   
}
```

Comment: Don't I need to add string and iomanip on the top as well as iostream? Or should I only use iostream for this assignment?

Comment: This particular question only needs `iostream`. This is what gives you the `cout` and `cin` functions. `string` is for functions related to strings (we're using integers), and `iomanip` is for formatting output (which we don't need to do here).

Comment: Thank you Xenon for your valuable input. I'm going to edit the coding and hope that it works. Appreciate all your help!

Comment: @NikiM Thanks for being polite and thanking folks for there help! But while you can thank a user that helped you by leaving a comment, You can also up-vote there answer by clicking the up arrow to the left, and/or accept there answer by clicking the checkmark to the left. That can show your gratitude as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. You probably *DON'T* need "cstdlib".
2. Instead, consider using "cin" and "cout":

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

```
int age;
cin >> age;
...
cout << "I am " << age << " years old.";
```

3. As far as "pause", one alternative is `std::cin.ignore();`:

[Is there a decent wait function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902261/is-there-a-decent-wait-function-in-c)

4. Of course, you also need a function `main()` somewhere, if you don't already have one.  Your example has no function, and won't compile as-is.

Comment: Why wouldn't he need a for loop? Assignment says to print numbers from 1 to  `n`.

Comment: You would need a loop for this unless you used some kind of abstraction that handles the loop for you.