# Why is my application closing even though I have cin.get();?

Tags: c++, cin

So as the title says, I dont want to use system("pause") because I dont want to develop a bad habbit.
And I cant figure out why it keeps closing even though I have cin.get();

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


float medel(int v[], int n)
{
    float res = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 

    {
        cin >> v[i];

        res += ((double)v[i] / n);
    }

    return res;


}

int main() {
    const int num = 10;
    int n[num] = { 0 };

    cout << "Welcome to the program. Enter 10 positive numbers: " << endl;;
    cin.get();
    cout << "The average of ten numbers entered is: " << medel(n, num) << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: char x, while(x != 'q') {cin.get();}

Comment: How are you learning C++?  `cin.get();` is not going to read in 10 numbers and it also it not storing what it did read in into anything. Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 4):

`cin.get()` consumes a single character from your input stream.

If there isn't one already there, the program will block waiting for one, which is your expectation.

However, there *is* one there: the newline from the <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress after your last `cin >> v[i]` operation.

[Don't use `cin.get()` to keep your application running at the end, anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36374595/560648).

By the way, your program's logic is flawed; you seem to prompt for positive numbers, then introduce the output, before actually asking for any input.

How about something like this:

```
int main()
{
    const int num = 10;
    int n[num] = { 0 };

    cout << "Welcome to the program. Enter " << num  << " positive numbers: " << endl;
    const float average = medel(n, num);
    cout << "The average of the numbers entered is: " << average << endl;
}
```

Find a way *outside* of your program to keep the terminal window open, if it's not already. That's not your program's job.

Comment: I recommend using `cin.ignore`, as in `cin.ignore(100000, '\n')`.  This will ignore characters until a newline is entered.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: I don't. There is no need for such tricks here

Comment: @BoundaryImposition I meant to ask you that, been a long day.

Comment: @RH6: Okay well as I've said a couple of times, my suggestion is _don't_! I gave some tips in the linked Q&A.

Comment: simplest way is to add "pause" to the PROJECT/name PROPERTIES/DEBUGGING Command Arguments in the project and use CTRL + F5 to run the project after it has been compiled.  @BoundarImposition is right in pointing out that your program should only do what is it supposed to do ...no more and no less.