# How to make program waiting in c++

Tags: c++, pause

I need to make program wait for some time until continue. I tried: `system("stop")` but console output was:
" 'stop' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
program or batch file.". I need answer in c++. Answers in [Is there a decent wait function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902261/is-there-a-decent-wait-function-in-c) doesn't work.

Comment: Waiting for what?

Comment: Waiting some time.

Comment: There are many ways to cause a thread to block. It depends on why you are blocking. If you just want to wait for a fixed amount of time, look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Comment: So you want the program to *pause*?

Comment: Yes. I want to pause program.

Comment: Sounds like you want your program to *sleep* rather than *pause*

Comment: _Probably yes._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a decent wait function in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902261/is-there-a-decent-wait-function-in-c)

Comment: It sounds like you're not sure what you want.  Can you provide more background on what you're trying to accomplish with this?  It is solely to look at the console output after execution?

Comment: @jaksia As a portable c++ solution you should have a look at [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) to really pause CPU consumption of your code for a minimum guaranteed amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

Following makes your program stop. At least for the next year or so. Roughly. Bonus: Its portable and doesn't drain your laptop's battery.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main() {
  using namespace std::chrono_literals;
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(8760h);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, you could pass `seconds`, `milliseconds` etc. You can look up for values that can be passed in `std::this_thread::sleep_for`

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work.